# I am stuck in calling a value of a key inside of dictionary which is inside of list but with random variable. its output is not the same as in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, key-value

I have tried to make a random number then that random number will be used to call follower_count from the dictionaries inside of the list data but I couldn't get the same follower for the randomly generated number not even close, the followers are also picked randomly

```
import random
data = [
    {
        'name': 'Instagram',
        'follower_count': 346,
        'description': 'Social media platform',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
        'follower_count': 215,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Portugal'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Ariana Grande',
        'follower_count': 183,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Dwayne Johnson',
        'follower_count': 181,
        'description': 'Actor and professional wrestler',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Selena Gomez',
        'follower_count': 174,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Kylie Jenner',
        'follower_count': 172,
        'description': 'Reality TV personality and Self-Made Billionaire',
        'country': 'United States'
    }
]
def comparison(followers_A,followers_B):
    if followers_A>followers_B:
        return followers_A
    else:
        return followers_B

def number():
    '''Generates Random numbers'''
    return random.randint(0,length)
def follower(number):
    '''Calls the follower in the list'''
    return data[number-1]['follower_count']
length=len(data)
print(f"{length} its the length of list")
print(f"{number()} its random number")
number=number()
follower = follower(number)
print(f"{follower} its followers")
print(data[11]['follower_count'])
```

Comment: (1) Better don't use variable names equal to function names. (2) You call `number()` twice and it usually returns a different number on each call.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. You're using the same name `number` and `follower` for both the function and the variable, which may lead to unexpected behavior.
2. In `data[number-1]['follower_count']`, the `-1` can be problematic if the random number is generated starting from `0`.
3. You're attempting to access `data[11]['follower_count']`, but the `data` list you provided is shorter (6 elements), so there's no 11th element that will lead to `IndexError`.
4. There's an inconsistency in the number function; it generates a random integer starting from `0` up to `length`, but the list index starts from `0` and goes up to `length - 1`.
5. Function `comparison()` is unused (dead code).

Here's refactored code with the above issues addressed:

```py
import random

data = [
    # ... (same as your data)
]

def generate_random_number(length):
    '''Generates Random numbers within range of list length'''
    return random.randint(0, length - 1)

def get_follower_count(index):
    '''Calls the follower in the list by index'''
    return data[index]['follower_count']

list_length = len(data)
random_index = generate_random_number(list_length)

follower_count = get_follower_count(random_index)

print(f"{list_length} is the length of list")
print(f"{random_index} is the random number")
print(f"{follower_count} is the follower count")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can makes matters easier if you use random.choice() to select the [random] dictionary from your list. Then you can do whatever you want with the selected dictionary:

```
# pseudo-randomly select a dictionary from the list
e = random.choice(data)
# print the follower_count
print(e['follower_count'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your coding as follows.
You have a list containing few dictionaries. A random number is generated among the total numbers of dictionaries in list. your program should get the data of generated random number of the list. From the selected selected dictionary, it should return the name and number of followers(Apart from these it should print the length of the list and the selected random number as well.
Hope my understanding is correct.

```
import random
data = [
{
    'name': 'Instagram',
    'follower_count': 346,
    'description': 'Social media platform',
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
    'follower_count': 215,
    'description': 'Footballer',
    'country': 'Portugal'
},
{
    'name': 'Ariana Grande',
    'follower_count': 183,
    'description': 'Musician and actress',
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Dwayne Johnson',
    'follower_count': 181,
    'description': 'Actor and professional wrestler',
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Selena Gomez',
    'follower_count': 174,
    'description': 'Musician and actress',
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Kylie Jenner',
    'follower_count': 172,
    'description': 'Reality TV personality and Self-Made Billionaire',
    'country': 'United States'
}
]

length=len(data)
number = random.randint(0,length)
dct = data[number-1]
Name = dct['name']
follower_count = dct['follower_count']
print(f"{length} its the length of list")
print(f"{number} its random number")
print(f"{Name} is his/her name")
print(f"{follower_count} are number of followers")
```

Hope this will be useful.